# Alias in Unix to Change Directory

Tags: shell, unix, command-line, alias

Hi everyone I am fairly new to Unix so forgive me!

I have the following .profile file that I use to assign aliases!

```
  alias here='export THERE_PWD=`echo $PWD`'
  alias there='cd $THERE_PWD'
```

Hopefully you can see what I am trying to do. Using the 'here' command I can specify where I eventually want to change directory back to after working in another directory (by typing 'there').

However, this doesn't seem to work! Where have I gone wrong?
This will save me a lot of time in the long run if I get it working!

Comment: Try using `THERE_PWD="{tickmark}cwd{tickmark}"`

Comment: Does `cd -` fit your requirements?   (`cd` uses the variable `$OLDPWD` when called with `-`)

Comment: Since you're new to Unix, you'd be better off learning how to use existing commands rather than invent your own: then when you have to use a new (to you) Unix host, can can get on and do your work without having to create aliases.

Comment: @ed, since you specify unix rather than linux, what is your shell? Is it bash/ksh/...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use the built in dir stack via `pushd` and `popd`:
`pushd new_dir` pushes the current dir onto the stack and changes to `new_dir`
`popd` returns to where you came from.

Comment: so would the alias for here simple be `here='pushd $PWD'`

Comment: Yes, you could do it that way. I'd use `alias here='pushd .'` and your `there` command is just `popd`. Personally I wouldn't bother with the aliases though. `pushd .` is concise enough.